# Origen de garnucho, garnuchazo

Tags: etimología, méxico, palabras-raras

Gracias a un episodio de [chespirito](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgkcWy4fABc) (en el min 10:35 aprox.), me quedó la duda de que era un *garrunchazo*. Luego de una breve búsqueda, encontré que la palabra era *[garnuchazo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=garnuchazo)*, que aparece en el DLE como [garnucho](https://dle.rae.es/?w=garnucho) y que es un mexicanismo reconocido desde 1992.

> m. Méx. Golpe que se da con el dedo medio después de retenerlo con el pulgar.

Según [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1800&content=garnucho%2C%20garnuchazo&smoothing=3&corpus=32&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgarnucho%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgarnuchazo%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgarnucho%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgarnuchazo%3B%2Cc0), las palabras tienen una leve aparición en el siglo XIX pero se consolidan de verdad en el siglo XX. Pero este golpe especial, que se da en todo el mundo, no tiene etimología alguna (o no aparece en una búsqueda). Quizá provenga de alguna lengua de Aridoamérica o de Mesoamérica, pero no es sino una especulación rápida.

Answer (score 3):

Solo unos apuntes, que por no responder del todo a la pregunta quizás deberían ir como comentario:

**Garnuchazo**:

- No aparece en el diccionario etimológico de Corominas.
- No aparece en el Fichero General de la RAE.
- No aparece ningún caso en el CORDE de la RAE.
- Un solo caso en el CORPES XXI de la RAE (un texto de México).

**Garnucho**

- No aparece en el diccionario etimológico de Corominas
- Con el significado "En Méjico, papirotazo" aparece en los diccionarios de **Alemany y Bolufer (1917) y de Rodríguez Navas (1918)** - en ninguno de los diccionarios se indica etimología alguna.
- No aparece en el Diccionario de Americanismos
- En el Fichero General de la RAE hay 6 fichas para "garnucho", definiéndolo como "en Méjico, capirotazo" o "papirote"; "dícese también *tafite*". [Solo una ficha](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_G/LETRA_G_PDF/GARNUCHO/00001522.pdf) recoge un texto mexicano del siglo XIX utilizando "garnucho".
- No aparece ningún caso en el CORDE de la RAE.
- No aparece ningún caso en el CORPES XXI de la RAE.

Comentario adicional: la variante utilizada en España parece ser [toba<sup>3</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/toba):

> De or. inc.
>
> 1. f. coloq. Esp. Pequeño golpe que se da impulsando los dedos índice o corazón con el pulgar.

Comment: In english this would be "To flick"? As in "He flicked the spider off of his arm".